# Differential Geometric Aspects of Rubber Bands

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

What happens, if a rubber band ( of length $l_0$ that has been stretched to length $l_1:=l_0+\Delta l\;$ and brought into the shape of a closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ) is released and if the only force at work is due to the elongation and obeys Hooke's law?

Clarification in response to Andreas' comment:
The force due to stretching shall be the same in each point of the rubberband.

Clarification in response to Hansen's comments:
for the mathematical discussion of the problem, it shall be assumed that $l_0=0$, so that the contraction doesn't stop as long as the rubber band has positive length.
Furthermore, I would like the mathematical question to be discussed on basis of points and vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$; physical phenomena like moment of inertia, or bending energy, etc., shall not play a role in this context.
I acknowledge however, that trying to model real-world rubber bands is also an interesting question to be tackled, after the questions related to the (over-)simplified model have been solved.

By "what happens", I mean

> - what kind of surface is traced out by an infinitely thin rubber band of infinitesimal small initial length $l_0$?
> - what are the coordinates of the point, to which the rubber band contracts, as its length tends to 0?
> - what are the trajectories of the points on the rubber band during contraction?

Comment: I assume you intend that the stretching should be uniform along the entire length of the rubber band.  In particular, you don't want that, for example, half of the rubber band remains unstretched while the rest stretches to cover the desired curve.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes, your assumption is right, the force due to elongation is the same in each point.

Comment: I think there may be a contradiction in your question: you assume that $l_0 = 0$ and that the force obeys Hooke's law, i.e. that it scales linearly with the strain relavive to the rest state. That would mean that the force is infinite for any $l_1 > 0$. Also, I think the band would not contract to a single point due to energy preservation: it would overshoot and keep oscillating like a spring does.

Comment: @JaapEldering I wrote that the initial length shall be infinitesimally small, which isn't the same as 0 (at least to my understanding); concerning your other point: I agree, that I didn't address all peculiarities of physical reality; but would they be of any help here?

Comment: What do you mean by infinitesimally small then, if not the same as 0? Please give a mathematical definition.

Comment: @Hansen infinitesimal small length shall mean Planck length for a physical interpretation and the same as $ds$ (as used in integrals over length) for a mathematical interpretation.

Comment: You have indicated neither a mathematical definition nor  physical one. $ds$ in integral is not defined per se. Whatever integral definition you choose, the whole integral is a limiting process, $ds$ is never a number. Even in functional analysis, $ds$ could be a shorthand for functional, but not a number. There is no such thing. As for Planck length, first of all, this is not a mathematical concept. Second, in physics at Planck length, there is no atom, much less a rubber band. Quantum mechanics or even string theory takes over. You are contradicting yourself either way.

Comment: @Hansen for a definition of infinitesimals see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal. My motivation for using an infinitesimally small initial length was to ensure that the rubber band can shrink beyond limit; it is a mathematical abstraction anyways. I would really appreciate some indication of how knowing the meaning of infinitesimally small helps in solving the problem.

Comment: "how knowing the meaning of infinitesimally small helps in solving the problem", how does one answer a question knowing not what is asked, particularly what the definition of the word "infinitesimal" means in the question? There are myriad definitions listed in the wiki-article, which one are you using? Almost all such definitions implies a limiting process or operation. Which one are you using? "Mathematical abstraction" calls for correspondingly mathematical precision. Your term "Planck scale" does not count as mathematically precise abstraction.

Comment: "rubber band can shrink beyond limit", what limit are you referring to? @JaapEldering is also asking you similar question. See his comments above and below his answer. If you do not think the concept of "infinitesimal" is relevant for your question, why don't you edit your question to set $l_0$ to be a finite positive number?

Comment: Regarding your second edit in response to Hansen: if you do not want to assume a physical model (which I think is indeed impossible if $l_0 = 0$), then you have to specify what model you do want to use: e.g. 1st or 2nd order dynamics, and how does it depend on curvature of the rubber band?

Comment: My model is, that the contracting force between two points is proportional to their shortest distance along the rubber band; that should suffice to investigate the mathematical abstraction. I have not much background in physics, so I can't tell, what the order of the dynamics would be. Curvature shall not have an influence on the magnitude of forces; it may however have an influence on their direction. The reason, why I don't want a "too physical" interpretation is, that I would also like to see, how well the simplified model fits more elaborate dynamical models.

Answer (score 5):

Let me give a shot at a partial answer, and provide a model of the problem that I hope is physically sensible. First, since we're actually dealing with a simplification of elasticity theory, and Hooke's Law can be viewed as a specific instance of linearized elasticity, this means that the stored energy function (i.e. potential energy density) is quadratic in strains away from the rest state of the rubber band. Let me here assume that the band has rest length $l_0 = 2\pi$ and that it is parametrized by $\phi\colon S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$. Then the stored energy is reasonably given by
$$
W(s) = \frac{k}{2}(\|\phi'(s)\| - 1)^2.
$$
Assuming a uniform mass density $\rho$, we have a Lagrangian
$$
L(\phi,\dot{\phi}) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\rho}{2}\|\dot{\phi}(s)\|^2 - \frac{k}{2}(\|\phi'(s)\| - 1)^2 \;ds.
$$
Since $L$ is invariant under translations (and rotations), the total momentum
$$
P = \rho \int_0^{2\pi} \dot{\phi}(s) \;ds,
$$
is a conserved quantity. Since $P = 0$ initially, and $P/\rho$ is the change of the center of mass, it follows that the center of mass is constant in time. In particular, if at any time the rubber band contracts to length zero, it will be at its center of mass point. This answers your second question. (Note that this derivation only depended on $L$ being invariant under translations, not the specific stored energy function.)

Comment: Don't mean to pooh-pooh this work, but isn't this result obvious for anyone knowing any physics at all? The trajectory of points on the rubber band or the rubber band curve at any time point would be more interesting.

Comment: @Hansen: I completely agree. But the OP's question missed any details on a possible physical model, so it was mostly for this reason that I posted this, including to point out that without dissipation, the band will never converge to a single point.

Comment: Yes. He should just let $l_0>0$ and ask, given the initial curve and, say, assuming the initial tension is all the same throughout the band, what the trajectory of the point on the rubber band is.