# Solving a Certain Constrained Isoperimetric Approximation-Problem

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, approximation-algorithms

This question is related to my question [Differential Geometric Aspects of Rubber Bands](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179721/differential-geometric-aspects-of-rubber-bands), where I asked for a mathematical model of contracting rubber bands.
In contrast to my former question, the situation is different here, because meanwhile I have devised a model, that seems appropriate and am now interested in solutions of the related *mathematical* questions (comments regarding physical aspects are however still welcome).

A model for rubber bands

- *prior* to contraction the rubber band is modelled as a closed curve of length $2\pi$ closed. continuous, length-parameterized curve $$x_0(u): [0,2\pi)\ni u\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$$ $$x_0(u+2\pi)=x_0(u)$$ $$\|\dot x_0(u)\|=1 $$
- *after* the rubber band has been released and $\Delta t$ seconds have passed, it is assumed that it has contracted to $x_{\Delta t}(u)$ of length $2\pi-\Delta s$ with the following properties: $$x_{\Delta t}(u):[0,2\pi)\ni u\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$$ $$x_{\Delta t}(u+2\pi)=x_{\Delta t}(u)$$  $$\|\dot x_{\Delta t}(u)\|=1-\frac{\Delta s}{2\pi}$$

Under the further assumption that the points of $x_0(u)$ are initially at rest and then are linearly accelerated on their way to position $x_{\Delta t}(u)$, it is possible to calculate the final speed from the distance of the initial and the final position and thus to obtain a factor for energy consumption:
$$s(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2\iff a=\frac{2s(t)}{t^2}$$
$$v(t) = at$$
$$E_{kin}(t)\ \propto\ \frac{1}{2}v^2(t) = \frac{2s^2}{t}$$

The total energy, $\Delta E_{kin}$, that is released during the time span $\Delta t$, in which the rubber band contracts from its initial state, that is modelled by $x_0(u)$, to its final state, modelled by $x_{\Delta t}(u)$, is proportional to the integral over the squared distances between corresponding curve points:
$$\Delta E_{kin}\ \propto\ \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\|x_0(u)-x_{\Delta t}(u)\|^2}{\Delta t}du}\ \propto\ \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\|x_0(u)-x_{\Delta t}(u)\|^2du}$$

> **Question:**
>
> given $x_0(u)$, $\Delta t$ and $\Delta s$ as defined above, how can the $x_{\Delta t}(u)$, with the stated properties, be determined, that minimizes $\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\|x_0(u)-x_{\Delta t}(u)\|^2du}$?